# Создаю свои собственные BB коды

Tags: php, bbcode

Сделал свой BB код, как можно сократить код?

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['text'])){
        $b = $_REQUEST['text'];
        $res = preg_replace('/(\[b\][a-z]\w*\[\/b\])/is', '<span class="bold">$1</span>', $b);
        $res2 = preg_replace('/\[b\]/', '', $res);
        $res3 = preg_replace('/\[\/b\]/', '', $res2);
        echo $res3;

        //Какой-то [b]text[/b], и цифры 123;
    }
?>

<head>
    <style>
        .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>" method="POST">
    <p><textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pWdCyi/1

Comment: Спасибо........

Comment: А почему такой не работает? preg_replace('/\[color\=\w*\](a-z\w*)\[\/color\]/is', '<span class="color">$1</span>', $bb)

Comment: [color=blue]text[/color]

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pWdCyi/2